# How to find local maximum in R from graph

Tags: r, function, max, local

I'm having a problem with my coding. I'm supposed to

1. Plot a graph of this equation [y=f(x)] where f(x) = (10*((x-1)^2)^(1/3))/(x^2 + 9) for 10001 values of x between (and including) -5 and 5
2. Among the 10001 x values in a, find the two local maximums of f(x).

I tried doing this :

```r
# question1
x <- seq(-5,5,length=10001)
y <- (10*((x-1)^2)^(1/3))/(x^2 + 9)

plot(x,y) # This will produce a graph with two max point

# question2
x[which.max(y)]
y[which.max(y)]
```

however, i only get the coordinates one of the maximum point and clueless as to how do i get another maximum point.

Comment: Finding *local maxima* is a common math question. And it is hard to due *well* in a general sense, especially with base R functions. BTW, please be careful to post *actual* R code: your code had three errors (`//` comment, mismatched parens with `{y)`, and `x` used before its definition, as Dave2e was nice enough to find/fix).

Comment: `which.max` finds the global maximum, so you can't do it in this way. This may be useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data

Comment: A common (but certainly not infallible) method is to take the derivative (`diff`) and find all tip-over points where the deriv crosses zero (pos-to-neg). (That may be what @yarnabrina's link is doing, I haven't looked at the code closely-enough.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find_peaks` from package `ggpmisc`.

```
library(ggpmisc)
x[ggpmisc:::find_peaks(df$y)]
y[ggpmisc:::find_peaks(df$y)]
```

The output is:

```
[1] -1.5  3.0
[1] 1.6373473 0.8818895
```

Note that the function `find_peaks` is noted as *internal*. You therefore need to access it using `:::`.

You can further parametrize the call to `find_peaks` using the `span` and `strict` argument. See `??find_peaks` for details.

You can also directly plot this using the `ggplot2` and `ggpmisc` packages:

```
x <- seq(-5,5,length=10001)
y <- (10*((x-1)^2)^(1/3))/(x^2 + 9)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + stat_peaks(col = "red")
```

[image]