# How to find the local minmum value in r?

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector as following, and I would like to find out the local min in the sequence. in this case, that is 5th and 15th elements, or as indicated in the plot. How can I do this?

```
f <- function(x)  ifelse(x < 15 & x >5, 80,(x-10)^2)
x <- seq(1,20) %>% f() 
x[8:12] <- 5
plot(x)

# x
#[1]  81  64  49  36  25  80  80   5   5   5   5   5  80  80  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

[image]

I have tried method described in [how to find local maximum in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342232/how-to-find-local-maximum-in-r-from-graph), yet it gives no result, I assume it's because that my data is discrete, not contineous.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836409/finding-local-maxima-and-minima

Comment: Try `which(diff(sign(diff(x)))>0)+1`

Comment: An other one : `which(diff(x)[-1] > 0 & diff(x)[-length(x)+1] < 0)+1`

Comment: many thanks, let me check.